# Getting data from Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a part of a code some thing like this:

```
def topLevel():
    bugsendwindows = Toplevel(background="grey")
    bugsendwindows.title("report bug")
    buglabel1 = Label(bugsendwindows, text='title', background="white")
    buglabel1.place(x=10, y=20)
    bugtitleentry = Entry(bugsendwindows)
    bugtitleentry.place(x=50, y=20)
    bugtitleentry.focus_set()
    buglabel2 = Label(bugsendwindows, text="email", background="white")
    buglabel2.place(x=10, y=60)
    bugemailentry = Entry(bugsendwindows)
    bugemailentry.place(x=60, y=60)
    bugemailentry.focus_set()
    buglabel3 = Label(bugsendwindows, text="data", background="white")
    buglabel3.place(x=10, y=100)
    bugdataentry = Entry(bugsendwindows)
    bugdataentry.place(x=60, y=100, height=60)
    bugdataentry.focus_set()
    def Enter():
        global bugtitleentry
        global bugemail
        global bugdata
        bugtitle = bugtitleentry
        bugemail = bugemailentry
        bugdata = bugdataentry
        localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
        bugwrite = open("bugreport", "w")
        bugwrite.write("title:")
        bugwrite.write(bugtitle, "\n")
        bugwrite.write("writer email:")
        bugwrite.write(bugemail, "\n")
        bugwrite.write("data:")
        bugwrite.write(bugdata, "\n")
        bugwrite.close()

    bugsend = Button(bugsendwindows, text="send",
        command=Enter)
    bugsend.place(x=10, y=150)
```

However, everytime I click send, It says something like this:

```
bugtitle = bugtitleentry
NameError: global name 'bugtitleentry' is not defined
```

how do i fix it so Enter can write the data to the file from topLevel?

Comment: There seems to be some problem with your indentation.  Is `Enter` nested inside `topLevel` or are they at the same level?

Comment: Enter is nested. BUt, if Enter is nested, can it get the data from topLevel Entries?

Comment: I modified the indentation of your code to hopefully correct it.  Feel free to fix it if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `Enter` is nested inside `topLevel`, it will pick up those names from the closure and no `global` statement is needed.

```
# ... <snip>
def Enter():
    bugtitle = bugtitleentry
    bugemail = bugemailentry
# </snip> ...
```

---

As a side note though, I'm not sure that the data writing will work as you expect.  You probably need to use the `.get()` method on the `Entry` objects.  e.g.:

```
bugwrite.write(bugtitle.get() + "\n")  # and file.write only takes 1 argument!
```

Comment: FWIW, python3.x has the `nonlocal` keyword to indicate that a variable is from a closure, but isn't global.  However, since you're not actually doing anything to change the value that is bound to the name, you don't need that either.

Comment: Im getting an error: TypeError: expected a character buffer object. On the line:bugwrite.write(bugtitle)

Comment: @user3167683 -- As I explained, you need to use the `.get()` method:  `bugwrite.write(bugtitle.get())`

Comment: THANK YOU!! It's working. I WILL NEVER FORGET YOU. Thank you.